# LinkedIn - can't send message

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, linkedin-api

I'm trying to send a message on LinkedIn with my web scraper but I am having trouble selecting the message input. The DOM updates depending if I focus on the input. Here's before focus: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSaX3.png and after focusing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6iOm.png

Any thoughts on how I can send a message?